# Js : format txt data to json data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Inside my app im loading some **txt data** from a **txt file** :

this txt file looks like this

**conosle.log(myData) :**

```
### Comment 1

## Comment two
dataone=1
datatwo=2
## Comment N
dataThree=3
```

I want to format my data to json so that

- i delete all comments lines (starting with # ) ; and also empty lines
- replacing all = with :
- adding quotes to my data attributes to be something like this
- wrap all inside { }

The result would be like this :

```
{
"dataone":"1"
"datatwo":"2"
"dataThree":"3"
}
```

is there any fastway to do it?

Comment: Why are you getting the data from a text file in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it sounds like you want something crude and simple, how about this:

```js
let dataObject = myData
  // split line-by-line first
  .split('\n')
  // drop comments, keep lines with = 
  .filter(line => !line.startsWith('#') && line.includes('='))
  // convert to [key, value] pairs
  .map(line => line.split('='))
  // collect pairs into object
  .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
     obj[key] = value.trim();
     return obj;
  }, {});

let json = JSON.stringify(dataObject);
```

#### Shortcomings

- Duplicate keys are not allowed. However most JSON library implementations do not accept them either.
- You will always get string values, even though a value like `"3"` could be represented as `3` in JSON.
- No attempt was made to provide any error handling for cases not shown in the original example txt

Comment: excellent ; thanks a lot ; just one thing ; must replace containes function with includes , since it causes some problem

Comment: @firasKoubaa, indeed, contains is now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#String.prototype.contains), thanks for spotting this.